# Change String Value After sometime

Tags: android

I need to change some "String value" each some time. Can someone tell how to do this?

I mean: AppStart > String value = "a" > 30second after > String value="b"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can post a task to main thread to update the textview after particular time. Refer the following code:

```
public class HistoryActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
TextView mTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);

    String history = getIntent().getStringExtra("History");

    mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtHistory);
    mTextView .setText(history);

    Handler handler=new Handler();

    final Runnable runnable=new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            //put your textview update code here
            mTextView .setText(history);
            handler.postDelayed(this,30*1000);//reschedule this runnable
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(runnable,30*1000);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to achieve the desired result:

```
private static final ScheduledExecutorService worker = 
Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

void someMethod() {
  Runnable task = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      /* Do something… */
    }
  };
  worker.schedule(task, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```